# perl Net::SSH2::Cisco key exchange algorithm sha1

Tags: perl, ssh, key, putty, sha1

**i need login with key exchange algorithm sha1**

> When i login b by program putty 
>   [I have this Message error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snBIx.png)
>   [image: I have this Message error]

```
my $session = Net::SSH2::Cisco->new(host => $host);
$session->login('login', 'password');
```

Comment: It looks like a warning, not an error message. What happens if you continue ?

Comment: can not  execute command